# Docker setup Ubuntu 16.04 - Job for docker.service failed

Tags: 16.04, docker

I am trying to get docker up and running on my Ubuntu 16.04 web server.

I have followed the installation instructions described here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

When I try to launch docker (docker run hello-world) I get the following message:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

When I try to launch the service:

```
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

I get the following error message:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2019-01-30 06:26:20 CET; 2min 34s ago
 Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Process: 17219 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17219 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation.

try running this:
running:

```
#"journalctl -fu docker"
```

That's what it comes out:

```
dockerd[7688]: time="2020-01-23T10:11:19.306442198+01:00" level=fatal msg="Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab127.2 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer."
```

That was the point for me. The Kernel need to be upgraded.